# Bash - while inside for loop not exiting

Tags: bash, shell, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm a beginner getting started with bash scripting.

I have 10 directories in current working directory dir1-dir10 + script.sh + a file called "tocopyfile".

Dir1-10 are empty.
tocopyfile is a test text file to be used for the purpose of my training
script.sh contains the following code:

```
dir=`pwd`
i="0"
for directory in `ls $dir`;do
        while [ $i -le 10 ]
        do
        cp tocopyfile $directory/file$i &
        i=$[$i+1]
        done
done
```

The script should copy 10 copies of the file "tocopyfile" to every dir (dir1-10) in the naming convention **file#**. The problem is that ones the script is exists after the first directory without executing the while loop to the remaining remaining dirs.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong please?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate issue is that you need to reset the value of `i` for each iteration of the outer loop.

```
for directory in `ls $dir`; do  # No! but more on that in a moment
    i=0
    while [ $i -le 10 ]
```

There are a few other issues with your code.

1. `dir=$(pwd)` is almost always pointless; `bash` already provides a variable `PWD` containing the name of the current working directory. You don't actually need this, though; you can simply use `./*/` to expand to a list of directories in the current working directory.
2. Never use the output of `ls` in a script.
3. `$[...]` is obsolete syntax; use `$((...))` instead.

---

Cleaning your code up a bit, we get

```
for directory in ./*/; do
    i=0
    while [ "$i" -le 10 ]; do
        cp tocopyfile "$directory/file$i" &
        i=$((i+1))
    done
done
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Quite helpful

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `$i` *inside* the `for` loop, such that `$i == 0` upon each iteration of your `while`:

```
dir=`pwd`
for directory in `ls $dir`;do
    i="0" # <===== notice the change here
    while [ $i -le 10 ]
    do
    cp tocopyfile $directory/file$i &
    i=$[$i+1]
    done
done
```

Other things you might want to change:

1. Double-quote all your variables (in the event they have spaces in them).
2. Use `$()` instead of the long-deprecated back-tick syntax.
3. Use `$(())` instead of the deprecated `$[]` syntax.
4. Tidy up your indentation.

Comment: Thanks for that quite helpful :)